# Scaling cells in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a table in range A5 to A100 I need to know if it is possible how to do it, for example I empty cell A44, cells from A45 onwards scale to fill up cell A44 that I have emptied, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DeleteThem()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim LastRowF As Long
  With ActiveSheet
    LastRowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  For i = 1 To LastRowF
    If Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
      Range("A" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
  Next i
End Sub
```